# How can I change the color of the traffic layer in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to change the standard traffic colors of the Traffic Layer of a Google Map?

Answer (score 1):

See [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) in the documentation.

For example the following example reduces the saturation on all features and disables labels on roads.

```
  var styles = [
  {
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#00ffe6" },
      { saturation: -20 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      { lightness: 100 },
      { visibility: "simplified" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];

map.setOptions({styles: styles});
```

I have create one example for you : see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73obwwkz/11/)

Comment: You are changing the map colors, not the ones for the traffic layer

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you are not currently able to edit the styles of the traffic layer.